# Jetpack Datastore: performance considerations

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose, persistence, android-jetpack-datastore

I'm creating a jetpack compose android application, and need some persistent data—it looks like jetpack DataStore is the right way to go.

For my application, I'm going to have a list of texts (lets say 20 texts that are all 10 paragraphs long), and the texts also have metadata (e.g., title). I'm trying to decide on the architecture of my datastore, and couldn't find much about the performance characteristics of it. I was reading aobut [proto buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3), but have never used them before.

Anyhow, would this architecture (using rough pseudocode) be reasonable:

```
type Texts = Map(uuid -> Text) # top level store in my DataStore

object Text {
   metatadata: {
      name: string,
      author: string
      preview: string   
   },
   textContent: long string or array of long strings
}
```

Would I be able to map over the values of the Map, and extract all the metadata, to display on a homescreen—without incurring the cost of reading all the large text content? Or do I need different top level data structures (one for text metadata, and one for text content)? Specifically, can I performantly subscribe to only the nested metadata within a `Composable`?

Comment: I would suggest better use database for such use case .. You can structure your data in better way and its easy to perform CRUD and write migrating for database .. 
You can not ship prefilled datastore anyway so i suppose you will store these values after the app is installed from some Source local or remote.  Can u answer this how will u get this data which u want to store in Data store ?

Comment: @ADM Ah, so this isn't the right use case for DataStore, that's just intended for storing preferences? Do you have a database to recommend for Compose? I mainly want to be able to subscribe to changes easily.

Comment: `datastore` basically a replacement for `SharePreference` API which used to store simple data key-values pairs .. For any complex data better to use database .. `android-room` is the recommended way to use relational database in android. u can explore it .. database do not depends on compose stuff as long as you have all the CRUD operation in place you can use any database. `android-room`  is the easiest way IMO.

Comment: @ADM can I do something like `val userEmail = dataStore.getEmail.collectAsState(initial = "")`. Can I do that with `android-room`, so that I can subscribe to db state that gets changed?

Comment: yeah just search for it .. [here is one example](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-room-using-kotlin-flow-in-jetpack-compose-7a720dec35f5)

Answer (score 1):

Whichever data storage system you prefer, or you can use both you can do it by  using Dependency Inversion using interface and injecting it via a DI framework.

You can create an `TextDataSource` interface and create implementations such  `RoomDataSourceImpl` or `DataStoreSourceImpl` for keeping local data but only exposing TextDataSource to your Repository/UseCase/ViewModel.

And, yes, by creating a Flow from room database with select anytime your data changes you can update the Flow.

Declare the function below in your `Dao` interface

```
   /**
     * get list of [TextEntity] as [Flow]
     */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_text")
    fun getTextsFlow(): Flow<List<TextEntity>>
```

Inside you ViewModel or Composable convert this flow or collect it as `State` with `Flow.collectAsState()` extension or change it to your custom ui state for instance

```
@Immutable
data class UiState<T>(
    val status: Status,
    val data: T? = null,
    val error: Throwable? = null
)
```

And i collect it as

```
/**
 * Get texts as [Flow] of [UiListState]
 */

val uiListState: Flow<UiListState<Text>> = textListUseCase
.getTextsFlow()
.map {
    when (it) {
        is Result.Error -> {
            UiListState(status = Status.ERROR, error = it.exception)
        }

        is Result.Success -> {
            UiListState(status = Status.SUCCESS, data = it.data)
        }

        else -> UiListState(status = Status.IDlE)
    }
}
.flowOn(dispatchers.defaultDispatcher)
.onStart {
    this.emit(UiListState(status = Status.LOADING))
    delay(1000)
}
```

UseCase is for executing business logic only, you can skip it if it's not required.

Official document below explains about UseCase and domain layer.

https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/domain-layer

Comment: This is one way of doing it with Room, clean architecture and Compose. Of course, there are many good ways to accomplish it

Comment: I ended up using `Room` instead of `DataStore`, and am currently using `LiveData`. Would you recommend directly using `Flow` over `LiveData`?

Comment: LiveData is Android component while Flow is Kotlin. It's a preference. In my humble opinion and how i do it. I didn't used to use LiveData, when it was popular, in Domain or Data layers because of this. I'd rather using RxJava before Flow was a thing, in ViewModel or Presenter subscribe/collect reactive stream/flow then convert it to LiveData for Ui layer. Now with Compose as i see in official documents there are no LiveData examples but only Flow. But it's up to you to decide. I'd rather not using it especially i'm planning to migrate KMM(multiplaform) soon

Comment: My choice is using interfaces that return Flow or suspend functions which makes changing from implementation of DB to another. KMM doesn't support room, so if wish to migrate to SQL Delight or Realm i think it would be less painless with Flows or suspend functions. Long story short, coding to interfaces or general reactive or observables would make your code easy to adapt to changes. Less Android code easier to adapt

Comment: I'm new to Android dev, and starting on a compose + material 3 stack, no legacy stuff. I'm currently not using MVVM, and don't think I'm likely to. I'll check out Flow—it looks like it has some pretty powerful ways to interpret the incoming stream from your example.

Comment: Yes. Flow is way more powerful than LiveData, with operators of Flow you can filter, timeout, catch errors, or change flows, and it's kotlin component which might give you more flexibility and platform independence. And i didn't mean MVVM, i meant clean architecture. You can have clean architecture while using MVP, VIPER, MVI or MVC. It's about separation of concerns and using abstraction over concrete classes and changes in inner layers not effecting your UI. You can change to SQL Delight or Realm one day with only minimal change on your Repository or DataSource implementation.